# How would you enqueue scripts in wordpress to show only on single posts & blog pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

How would you enqueue a script in a theme that you only want to show on the blog and single posts?

I checked other questions here but didn't get convincing answer.

I got the following code from Wordpress site from a question as :

```
function enqueue_files() {
  if ( is_page( 'your-page' ) ) {
    // enqueue specific page script files here
  } else {
    // enqueue common scripts here
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_files' );
```

So after taking a look at [**`is_page()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_page/) function I am confused that as I need to only show them at single posts & blog pages and while the following function would work only for static pages and since I want it to be dynamic for all of single posts pages and blog pages so how would I be able exactly to do that then with which function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enqueue specific scripts only for the blog homepage and single posts of post type `post`:**

```
function enqueue_files() {      

    if ( is_singular('post') || is_home() ) {
        // enqueue specific scripts for blog homepage and single posts of post type post
    } else {
        // enqueue common scripts here
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_files' );
```

---

### Explanation

- [`is_singular('post')`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) checks if a singular post of specified post type `post` is being displayed (thanks @Umair Shah Yousafzai for this hint)
- [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) determines if the query is for the blog homepage

Comment: Would you explain your approach for the solution as I am confused to look at the code?

Comment: I can understand the `is_home()` as it will only come true for the posts page under reading settings so if the blog page is not set so then it won't work right??

Comment: Downvote, because `get_post_type()` will not work just anywhere. This would only work in certain locations, like the `single.php` template. Anywhere where there is not a global `$post` (or the loop has changed) may give unexpected results.

Comment: @JakeParis - I've updated my answer. Check with the global post object will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `is_singular`. It combines `is_page()` with `is_single()`.
[Linky](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular).

It'll also activate on `attachment` pages though. If that's a problem for you, just use `is_page() || is_single()`.

You don't need to pass the page/post slug (and it'll actually break what you are trying to accomplish. So you just do:

```
if ( is_page() || is_single() ) {
// if ( is_singular() ) { // or this if you prefer. :)
    // enqueue specific page script files here
}
```

If you want to detect the blogroll, use `is_home`, I thought you were only targeting single posts.

[Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/).

Comment: I am confused now...the same function with just `OR` in between how will it work any different as these are both the same function?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. :P

Comment: He asked for blog and single posts. `is_single()` works for any post type, except attachments and pages. And `is_page()` just for pages.

Comment: @JakeParis : What about this? `is_single()` will also return true for custom post types, if you want to be 100% sure it's a post then use `is_singular('post')`

Comment: If you want to specify a post type you can do it, of course. In your q it wasn't specified so I didn't. Whatever floats your vote. ;)

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai - `is_singular('post')` is great. I did not know that.

Comment: Is `is_page()` considered to show single post and blog??? As to what I think it will only come true for pages not posts and blog right?? So would you like to update your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "blog". You mean the blogroll or index? Either way `is_page` only works for pages.

Comment: As I said, you use is_singular for other post types, and is_page for pages. To detect the blogroll, you use is_home